# Angular scope variable not updated on $broadcast

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie to AngularJS and I faced a problem when using        `$scope.$broadcast('update:button:label', {label: 'Edited'})` from a controller. This event is being listened to by a directive `buttonStatus`:

```
$scope.$on('update:button:label', function(event, data) {
   $scope.buttonlabel = data.label;
});
```

The `buttonlabel` variable is updated but the change is not shown in the template used by the `buttonStatus`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$broadcast` dispatches an event downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered listeners. So if the directive is not inside the controller's scope, its $scope would never receive any event.

A simple solution here is using `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$rootScope.$on` to handle messages.

Comment: the action is being listened and the scope variable is updated. it is just that in the template it is not changed.

Comment: Can you provide a demo app hosted on jsfiddler or plnkr for better debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are creating a new scope inside your directive. In such a case any change in the child scope wouldn't be reflected in the parent scope for changes in primitive datatypes.Try using the scope variable like `$scope.someObj.buttonlabel` .If you could create a plunker for the problem, it would become clearer.
See Here for [angular directive scope inheritance rules.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#directives)